# Inbound emails domain with Mandrill

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp, mail-server, mandrill

I am using Mandrill mail server for sending emails to users and I have my own domain added to Mandrill to send out mails. Suppose I have configured Mandrill to use `info@mydomain.com` to send out emails and then it should send mails which it does. And any reply sent to `info@mydomain.com` will be forwarded to traditional mailboxes.

Now I have a doubt on receiving emails via Mandrill, once I add an inbound domain and route its path to my desired location, it should be ready to receive mails. Well I have read my questions on SO and it has been said that if someone wants to use traditional mailboxes for receiving mails then its better not to use Mandrill or use a custom sub domain.

Also it has been said that it is not possible for Mandrill to receive mail which is already configured or forwarded to some other traditional mailboxes.

So I added a sub domain to Mandrill's inbound domain like `inbound.mydomain.com` and receive emails on this domain which will be received by Mandrill and will be send to the desired route which we set up. Now I will have to change my sender domain with the same that is `inbound.mydomain.com` to make users reply to this domain which will be received at Mandrill. What I want is :

1. Send mails using `info@mydomain.com`
2. Receive mails to my location using inbound domains

Comment: ok i will post it there too

Comment: what should be done for this